# Twilio Outbound Call Recording

Tags: twilio, phone-call, recording, outbound

With Twilio we make outbound calls:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc1....4658a/Calls.json' \
-d 'From=%2B44987654321' \
-d 'To=%2B123456789' \
-d 'Url=http%3A%2F%2Fourdomain.com%2Ftwiml.php%3Faction%3Dcall_is_taken' \
-u ACc1....4658a:{AuthToken}
```

Not that it matters, but when someone picks up the phone, our response twiml code (which will change) is just:

```
<Response><Say>Thank you for picking up.</Say></Response>
```

We can add a [`<Record>` in our Twiml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) code to start recording a section, but we want to record the ENTIRE call (including Twiml voice and human voice), right from the START till the END of the outbound call.

I could find the `<Dial record="true">`, but thats for calling outside the call. I did try `<Response record="true">`, but that didn't give me any recording SIDs either, it's not documented anyway.

How do I record the entire call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out myself. This will record an entire conversation:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc1....4658a/Calls.json' \
-d 'From=%2B44987654321' \
-d 'To=%2B123456789' \
-d 'Record=true' \
-d 'Url=http%3A%2F%2Fourdomain.com%2Ftwiml.php%3Faction%3Dcall_is_taken' \
-u ACc1....4658a:{AuthToken}
```

The only thing added was the `-d 'Record=true'` parameter. I couldn't quite find it in the documentation though.

Comment: Refer to the RecordingURL parameter here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request

Comment: Here more details https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-record-a-phone-call-with-twilio about recordings